# Remapping multiple columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, dictionary, dataframe, remap

I want to remap values in several columns of my DataFrame: from [site1] to [site5].

Here is my dictionary:

```
new_dict
{'accounts.google.com': 5,
'apis.google.com': 7,
'football.kulichki.ru': 9,
'geo.mozilla.org': 3,
'google.com': 4,
'mail.google.com': 6,
'meduza.io': 10,
'oracle.com': 2,
'plus.google.com': 8,
'vk.com': 1,
'yandex.ru': 11}

    site1   site2       site3       site4           site5        user       
0   vk.com  oracle.com  oracle.com  geo.mozilla.org oracle.com   1      

1   vk.com  google.com  google.com  google.com       0           2
```

Is there a way to remap these columns at the same time?
I'm trying this approach, but it doesn't work in any way...

```
df_train['site%d' %(range(1,11))].replace(new_dict)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter columns by `mask` with [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and apply `replace`:

```
m = df_train.columns.str.startswith('site')
df_train.loc[:, m] = df_train.loc[:, m].replace(new_dict)
```

Or:

```
df_train.update(df_train.loc[:, m].replace(new_dict))

print (df_train)
   site1  site2  site3  site4 site5  user
0      1      2      2      3     2     1
1      1      4      4      4     0     2
```

**Detail**:

```
print (m)
[ True  True  True  True  True False]


print (df_train.loc[:, m])
    site1       site2       site3            site4       site5
0  vk.com  oracle.com  oracle.com  geo.mozilla.org  oracle.com
1  vk.com  google.com  google.com       google.com           0
```

---

If never values from dict in another columns simpliest is:

```
df_train = df_train.replace(new_dict)
```